# Help theming media wiki

Tags: css, wiki, mediawiki

Ive installed media wiki as a part of my website. How do i theme media wiki so that it looks like my site? The guide refers to a common.css. Where is this file? How do i go about editing it? I cant just use my site css file rite?

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about Mediawiki skins. Here's a [how to create](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-MediaWiki-Skin-Based-on-the-MonoBook-Skin). Here's a [list of skins](http://mediawiki2u.com/).

Other links (from MediaWiki):

1. [Brief overview](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Skins)
2. [Long manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning)
3. [Configuration information](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skin_configuration)

I can't give you a quick how to here (not possible) - your best bet is just to read these links.

Answer (score 0):

here is an ebook for  mediawiki admin..... this will help you i think....
http://ifile.it/74uhki5/mewiadmin.rar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @andrew you are right. but actually i dont know much about mediawiki. when i search i got this link and i just shared with the people. sometimes it may help. thanks for the comment andrew. i accept you comment. have a nice day, cheers!!